# Minimizing with constraints

Tags: mathematical-optimization, constraint

I would like to minimize the following function with respect to x:

```
f[x_] := b/Sqrt[x] + ( 4.5 c x^6 Log[x] )^(1/3)
```

where `b` and `c` are constants. That is, I would like to find `x`, as a function of `b` and `c`, that minimizes `f`.

I've tried using `Minimize[f, x]`. I have also tried solving `df/dx = 0` to find the turning point (and therefore finding the minimum). However, neither of these approaches work.

From what I can tell, one problem is that `f` doesn't have a minimum for all values of `b` and `c`. However, for the ranges of values of `b` and `c` that I'm interested in, `f` does have a minumum. But I can't work out how to put restictions on `b` and `c`.. Specifically, I want:

```
0< c < 1 && b > 0, && x > 1
```

How can I minimze `f` with respect to `x`, with the above constraints? I've worked through Mathemica's help pages, but can't find a working solution to this.

If this problem above isn't solvable, then a simpler but still useful problem would be to minimize `f` for a given value of `b`. For example, take `b = 10` then find `x` as a function of `c` that minimizes `f`. Again, the constraints `0 < c <1` and `x > 1` hold.

Comment: Start by defining `f` as `f[x_, b_, c_] := ...` so the dependence on $a,b,c$ is made evident. You could then try `Minimize[{f[x, b, c], 0 < c < 1, b > 0, x > 1}, {x, b, c}]`. Can you also elaborate on how you know that the function has a minimum under those conditions?

Comment: As a simple example plot would suggest, this function has no global minimum in the case `b=10` and `c=1/2` because the boundary point `1` is not feasible.

Comment: I was a bit vague saying that I know that f does have a minimum, but here's my thinking: first I should say that c=1/n, and my whole goal in this is to find how large n has to be to make f close to zero. Now fix b>0 and n>0. For x->zero the left hand term, b/sqrt(x), tends to infinity. But for x->infinity the right hand term also tends to infinity. But somewhere in the middle, where sqrt(x)>b and x^6<n, both terms are small. Hence there must be intermediate values of x that minimise f!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be no way to find the minimum analyticaly.

A way out is to "FindRoot" of the x where the first derivative is zero for given b an c.

```
f[x_, b_, c_] = b/Sqrt[x] + (45/10 c x^6 Log[x])^(1/3)

dequ[x_, b_, c_] = 
   FullSimplify[D[f[x, b, c], x] == 0, {0 < c < 1, b > 0, x > 1}]

(*    6^(2/3) c^(1/3) x^(5/2) (1 + 6 Log[x]) == 3 b Log[x]^(2/3)     *)
```

Find the x value of the minimum for given b and c, ignoring error messages.

```
fr21[b_, c_] := (xf = x /. FindRoot[dequ[x, b, c], {x, 2, 1, 100}]) //
                 Quiet

Plot3D[fr21[b, c], {b, 0, 12}, {c, 10^-3, 1}]
```

[image]

Control it, showing the minimum for given b,c

```
pl[b_, c_] := 
   Plot[f[x, b, c], {x, 1, 12}, 
    Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Red, 
      Point[{fr21[b, c], f[fr21[b, c], b, c]}]}]

Manipulate[pl[b, c], {{b, 10}, 0, 20}, {{c, 1/2}, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this Akku, this is very helpful.